# What might be the best way to benchmark a users PC, PHP or JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

**PHP** - Apache with Codeigniter

**JS** - typical with jQuery and in house lib

**The Problem:** Determining (without forcing a download) a user's PC ability &/or virus issue

**The Why:** We put out a software that is mostly used in clinics, but can be used from home, however, we need to know, before they go to our mainsite, if their pc can handle the enormities of our web-based, browser-served software.

**Progress:** So far, we've come up with a decent way to test dl speed, but that's about it.

**What we've done:** In php we create about a 2.5Gb array of data to send to the user in a view, from there the view calculates the time it took to get the data and then subtracts the php benchmark from this time in order to get a point of reference of upload/download time. This is not enough.

Some of our (local) users have been found to have "crappy" pc's or are virus infected and this can lead to 2 problems. (1)They crash in the middle of preforming task in our program, or (2) their virus' could be trying to inject into our js thus creating a bad experience that may make us look bad to the average (uneducated on how this stuff works) user, thus hurting "our" integrity.

I've done some googling around, but most plug-ins or advice forums/blogs i've found simply give ways to benchmark the speed of your JS and that is simply not enough.  I need a simple bit of code (no visual interface included, another problem i found with one nice piece of js lib that did this, but would take days to remove all of the authors personal visual code) that will allow me to test the following 3 things:

1. The user's data transfer rate (i think we have this covered, but if better method presented i won't rule it out)
2. The user's processing speed, how fast is the computer in general
3. possible test for infection via malware, adware, whatever maybe harmful to the user's experience

What we are not looking to do: repair their pc! We don't care if they have problems, we just don't want to lead them into our site if they have too many problems. If they can't do it from home, then they will be recommended to go to their nearest local office to use this software "in house" so to speak.

**Further Explanation**

We know your can't test the user-side stuff with PHP, we're not that stupid, PHP is mentioned because it can still be useful in either determining connection speed or in delivering a script that may do what we want.  Also, this is not a software for just anyone on the net to go sign up and use, if you find it online, unless you are affiliated with a specific clinic and have a login name and what not, your not ment to use the sight, and if you get in otherwise, it's illegal.  I can't really reveal a whole lot of information yet as the sight is not live yet.  What I can say, is it mostly used by clinics/offices for customers to preform a certain task.  If they don't have time/transport/or otherwise and need to do it from home, then the option is available.  However, if their home PC is not "up to snuff" it will be nothing but a problem for them and make the 2 hours task they are meant to preform become a 4-6hour nightmare.  Thus the reason, i'm at one of my fav quest sights asking if anyone may have had experience with this before and may know a good way to test the user's PC so they can have the best possible resolution, either do it from home (as their PC is suitable) or be told they need to go to their local office.  Hopefully this clears things up enough we can refrain from the "sillier" answers.  I need a REAL viable solution and/or suggestions, please.

Comment: How do you plan on testing a user's processing speed with PHP, which only runs on the server-side?

Comment: Don't know about you, but getting forced to download 2.5 jiggabytes of data in a browser just to see if I'm allowed to use a website will make me blacklist the site instantly, and intensify my desire to hunt down and torture the developers to death with a 300baud modem.

Comment: @SpYk3HH You don't need 2.5Gb to calculate someones connection speed; you can send a 10Mb file followed by a bunch of smaller ones and you get an even better picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has (virtually) no access to information about the client's computer. Data transfer can just as easily be limited by network speed as computer speed. Though if you don't care *which* is the limiter, it might work.

JavaScript can reliably check how quickly a set of operations are run, and send them back to the server... but that's about it. It has no access to the file system, for security reasons.

**EDIT:** Okay, with that revision, I think I can offer a real suggestion - basically, compromise. You are not going to be able to gather enough information to absolutely guarantee one way or another that the user's computer and connection are adequate, but you can get a general idea.

As someone suggested, use a 10MB-20MB file and several smaller ones to test actual transfer rate; this will give you a *reasonable* estimate. Then, use JavaScript to test their system speed. But don't just stick with one test, because that can be heavily dependent on browser. Do the research on what tests will best give an accurate representation of capability across browsers; things like looping over arrays, manipulating (invisible) elements, and complex math. If there is a significant discrepancy between browsers, then use different thresholds; PHP *does* know what browser they're using, so you can give the system different "good enough" ratings depending on that. Limiting by version (like, completely rejecting IE6) may help in that.

Finally... inform the user. Gently. First let them know, "Hey, this is going to run a test to see if your network connection and computer are fast enough to use our system." And if it fails, tell them which part, and give them a warning. "Hey, this really isn't as fast as we recommend. You really ought to go down to the local clinic to perform this task; if you choose to proceed, it may take a lot longer than intended." Hopefully, at that point, the user will realize that any issues are on them, not on you.

Answer (score 0):

What you've heard is correct, there's no way to effectively benchmark a machine based on Javascript - especially because the javascript engine mostly depends on the actual browser the user is using, amongst numerous other variables - no file system permissions etc. A computer is hardly going to let a browsers sub-process stress itself anyway, the browser would simply crash first. PHP is obviously out as it's server-side.

Sites like [System Requirements Lab](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/intro.aspx) have the user download a java applet to run in it's own scope.